# Qt6 Change Scope of QSettings

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qt6

As the title says, I want to change the scope that my QSettings instance uses, however, I cant reassign my variable because the assignment and copy constructor are privated. (Also, why are they privated??)

I instatiate my original QSettings using Native Format, User Scope and Organization which I use to read the users dimensions to recreate it next time, when in production mode, I then want to change the scope to System, while in Test mode it should stay in user scope.

I know of setPath, but that requires a file path, which I don't want to manually generate when normally QSettings does that. I'd prefer to keep a single instance of QSettings rather than having 2 of them, one of which I'd use for a single value then never again.

Comment: `QSettings` can't be copied/assigned because it inherits from `QObject`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator

Comment: You could use a `QScopedPointer` (or `std::unique_ptr`) and reassign that when you want to swap-out the `QSettings` instance

Comment: @perivesta Is there any specific reason why they dont want to allow it to be used as a value?

Comment: It says on the page I linked: "The reasoning is found in the discussion on [Identity vs Value](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/object.html#identity-vs-value)"